# Integral Solution Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Show that if there are integral solutions to the equation $ax+by+cz=e$, then $\gcd(a,b,c)\mid e$.

Now, suppose that $gcd(a,b,c)\mid e$. Show that there are integers $w$ and $z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)w + cz=e$.

Then show that there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)w$.

Comment: Done.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I have not tried much. I said that if (a,b,c)=d; since d|a,d|b, and d|c, it follows that d|(ax+by+cz) for all integers x,y, and z. and if ax+by+cz=e, then d|e, so (a,b,c)|e, but I did not know how to approach the other parts. @user254665

Comment: Are you familiar with Bezout's identity? (Although it goes back to Euclid more than 2000 years ago) : If $\gcd (u,v) =1$, there are integers $x,y$ with $ux+vy=1.$ So if  $\gcd (s,t)=d,$ let $s=s'd$ and $ t=t'd.$ Then $\gcd (s',t')=1$ so there are integers$ x,y$ with $xs'+yt'=1,$ which implies $xs+yt=d.$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, assume $gcd(a,b,c) = \alpha$. Then, by the division algorithm,  $a = \alpha q$, $b = \alpha p$, $c = \alpha r$, for some integers $p,q,r$. The equation then becomes: $$\alpha px + \alpha qy + \alpha rz = e$$ dividing by $\alpha$, we see that $$px + qy + rz = \frac{e}{\alpha} $$ for the solutions to be integral, both sides of the equality must be integer valued, so $\alpha$ must divide $e$. As there wasn't really a question asked, I don't know which part you're struggling with. See if you can use this work to figure out the rest. Division algorithm will be your friend.

Comment: Apparently, you are supposed to try and prove the various parts (3 parts), but yeah, I was pretty lost as well.